# When should Akka BackoffSupervisor OnStop be used instead of OnFailure?

Tags: akka, persistence

We have been using Akka `BackoffSupervisor` for a few cluster singleton actors that are critical for the system and should always be present. These actors are persistent so in case DB failure they need to be restarted. Our code used `OnFailure` condition. However when the child persistence failed due the database error both the child and backoff supervisor were stopped and not restarted.

Should we use `OnStop` instead of `OnFailure`? It's not explained when each of the should be used and since the child actor fails in case of the database error our assumption was that we could use `OnFailure`. But perhaps since an actor is unconditionally terminated on persitence error `OnFailure` is never invoked and `OnStopp` should be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is "yes": in case the supervised actor is stopped unconditionally, it triggers the event OnStop that can be monitored to start a new incarnation of it.